# Android ObjectAnimator with constant speed

Tags: android, objectanimator

I used ObjectAnimator to rotate my view from 0 to 360 degree. But the speed of rotation is not constant. I need a constant speed as the animation should repeat a few times. Any acceleration in speed disturbs the consistency of the animation. This is my code:

```
ObjectAnimator animRotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ivLoader,"rotation", 0,360);
animRotate.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            animRotate.start();
        }
});
animRotate.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out [Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator) class, default one for `ValueAnimator` (`ObjectAnimator` is extending it) is:

```
private static final TimeInterpolator sDefaultInterpolator =
        new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
```

it will accelerate during "starting phase" and decelate on end. you want linear interpolation so:

```
ObjectAnimator animRotate = ...
animRotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animRotate.addListener(... // rest of code
```

but consider replacing `AnimatorListener` with

```
animRotate.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

there is also `setRepeatCount` method